# ASP.NET 4.5 OAuth using MySQL

Tags: asp.net, mysql, oauth, webforms, dotnetopenauth

I've created a project using the default templante from ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms Site and set my MembershipProvider to MySQLMembershipProvider, but the OAuth is using another storage in the App_Data folder called DefaultConnection.mdf.

How do I use the same database for my OAuth as I'm using for the default Membership?

I've never used OAuth before, so is there a Provider for MySQL or even a EF Provider or is there a way for it to use the default ADO.NET provider already defined for my application?

ps: Everything I know about ASP.NET came from "Pro ASP.NET 4 in C# 2010", and there's nothing about OAuth around there kkk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer...

Just created the two required tables inside my database: UserOpenAuthAccounts and UsersOpenAuthData.

My default ConnectionString used to be named AppConnection then I renamed it to DefaultConnection and then everything just worked out fine.

It would be cool to know where we can change the OpenAuth ConnectionString name not the default ConnectionString name.